# C#: What should my regex be to match this?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a URL and I'd like to match the ending of it exactly.

The url is [some_host]/url/action
If the URL contains "url/action" in it I'd like for it to be matched.

Additional Rule 1:
The URL can contain more data on the end e.g. "[some_host]/url/action/newTransaction/" -- in this case I'd like for the regex to not match it.

Additional Rule 2:
However if the URL is "[some_host]/url/action?t=true then I'd like for the regex to match.

What should my regex look like?

EDIT:
Some examples:

```
"[some_host]/url/action" -- should match. 
"[some_host]/url/action/" -- should match.
"[some_host]/url/action?t=true" -- should match 
"[some_host]/url/action/?t=true" -- should match 



 "[some_host]/url/action/[ANYTHING_ELSE]" -- should NOT match
```

Comment: so basically you want to match exactly for 'url' with three `/` ?

Comment: No. I've added some examples into the question

Comment: does `[some_host]` always http or https? also, does the second part of the url always url followed by action or its already a template (meaning, catch all, as long as valid for url -- ie. `http://somewhere.com/some_url/some_action?parameter=1`)?

Comment: It will always be http or https. I would like to give the regex lots of URL's and it should only catch URL's that have the string "url/action" in it and in addition also match the examples I have added

Comment: Do you want this? https://regex101.com/r/Qsz19N/1

Comment: does `?t=true` also to be caught, is there any other variation? or its just always having `url/action` and optionally have parameter `t=true`?

Answer (score 0):

This works your case:

```
(http|https):\/\/[\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+)\/url\/action(?!\/\w)[\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-]*
```

Use the full match in the above regex.

https://regex101.com/r/eGCYf6/2

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regex, is verbose. BUT, is easy to understand.

```
string url = "";
bool b1 = url.EndsWith("/url/action");
bool b2 = url.EndsWith("/url/action/");
bool b3 = url.EndsWith("/url/action/?t=true");
bool b4 = url.EndsWith("/url/action/?t=false");
bool match = b1 || b2 || b3 || b4;
```